# Page was zoomed out when width went down to 990px

Tags: css, styling

I am having trouble with css about entire page. Here is my page when I look on responsive size: 990px x 789px

[image]

and here is page at size 1024px x 789px which is good :

[image]

Code base css:

```
    .filter-body-wrapper
        padding: 0
        width: 94%
        margin: auto

        .filter-type
            border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(2,150,136)
            .single-item
                margin: 10px auto
                width: 97%
                &.disabled
                    opacity: .5
        .area-filter
            display: flex
            align-items: center
            padding-left: 1rem
    .clear-filters
        text-align: center
        padding: 10px 0

        button
            background: none
            text-decoration: none
            border: none
            border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(11,60,190)
            margin: 10px 0
            padding: 0 2px
            cursor: pointer

@media screen and ( max-width: 990px )
    .filter-wrapper
        background-color: white
        position: absolute
        right: -40%
        top: 125px
        transition: .5s all
    #filter-box
        transition: .5s all
        z-index: 1
    #filter-box.display
        transition: .5s all
        right: 0
    .two.columns
        width: 25%

@media screen and ( max-width: 600px )
    .filter-wrapper
        right: -100%
        top: 0
        min-height: 100vh
    .filter-options-table
        border: none
        .filter-options.header
            .back-btn
                display: inline
    .two.columns
        width: 100%
    #filter-box
        position: fixed
        z-index: 9
        top: 0
        right: -100%
        bottom: 0
        transition: .5s all
    #filter-box.display
        right: 0
        overflow-y: scroll
        transition: .5s all
```

I can provide website for example if need to
The error will appear whenever the size width went down to >990px

Comment: drop your website link or html here

Comment: remove `html {overflow-x: visible; } body {overflow: visible;}` @nhan Nguyen

Comment: It didn't changed anything

Comment: now it's working here

Comment: Oh Wait yes it worked! Thanks man! Can you add the answer so I can check it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment or remove both `html` and `body` property `overflow` property in css

```css
html {
  /* overflow-x: visible; */
} 
body {
  /* overflow: visible; */
}
```